# How to start a new activity on navigation drawer item click its not working in my code

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Almost every link every stack questions I referred already so please can anyone tell that what is my mistake in my code..
Following is my code:

```
public class Attdce extends Activity{

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;
    String mTitle="";
    private String[] information;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);

        mTitle=(String)getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        information=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Information);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, information));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //Updated Attdce.this instead of Attendace.this
                Toast.makeText(Attdce.this, information [position]+ " was selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    selectItem(position);
            }

        });
        drawerListener=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle("Select");
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
public void selectItem(int position)
            {

                setTitle(information[position]);
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                Intent intent1;
                 switch(position){
                 case 0:
                     intent1 = new Intent(Attdce.this, AboutUs.class);
                     startActivity(intent1);
                     break;

                 case 1:
                     intent1 = new Intent(Attdce.this, Features.class);
                     startActivity(intent1);
                     break;

                 case 2:
                     intent1 = new Intent(Attdce.this, Help.class);
                     startActivity(intent1);
                     break;

                 case 3:
                     intent1 = new Intent(Attdce.this, SMSCredits.class);
                     startActivity(intent1);
                     break;

                 case 4:
                     intent1 = new Intent(Attdce.this, ChangePassword.class);
                     startActivity(intent1);
                     break;

                 case 5:
                     intent1 = new Intent(Attdce.this, Help.class);
                     startActivity(intent1);
                     break;

                 }
            }

            public void setTitle(String title)
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(title);
            }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
         if(drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
                return true;
            }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

 @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            drawerListener.syncState();
        }


}
```

ACTIVITY_ATTENDANCE.XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"

         android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#111"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#009688"
       android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>

    //other xml code

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >
```

Can anyone please suggest me.. What is the problem??? I didn't get any error Navigation drawer is shown properly but when I select on navigation Drawer item so no any other activity is open..

Comment: can you see Toast message ?

Comment: have you defined your activities in manifest?

Comment: update your manifest

Comment: @KaranMer ya I checked that all activities defined in manifest..

Comment: actually what error or any problem you are seeing?

Comment: @bhargav ya I know I write attendance.this instead of Attdce.this I correct it already.

Comment: for drawer item click please visit this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: @sud No error nothing just when I clicked on items in navigation drawer no new activity is open.. And I already check my Manifest file.. All activities are defined.

Comment: usually with navigation drawer list items you should use fragments

Comment: is your drawer item click listener working properly ? have you checked? try to check in debugger mode

Comment: @Asmi I am just asking you that Is Toast printing or not

Comment: @bhargav Sorry.. Nothing shows when I clecked

Comment: make sure you use `ListView.OnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion please start using [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) recommended by android. In case you are searching for tutorials [here](http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/) you can find detailed example of how to use [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) in android.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the drawer, before                                            `startActivity(intent1)`

```
case 5:
                     final intent1 = new Intent(Attdce.this, Help.class);
                                drawer.closeDrawers();
                                drawer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        startActivity(intent1 );
                                    }
                                }, 200);
                               break;
```